# What could be the fix for Calling a method on null object base.Request.Headers issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, static-analysis

Some static code analysis tool giving error for below code where I am trying to access the `ControllerBase.Request` method and it's saying trying to access a method of `null` object `t base.Request.Headers`.

These all place same error, what could be the ideal fix here?

```cs
// Method 1
if ((bool)Request.Headers?.TryGetValue("CallerId", out values)) 

// Method 2
var x = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["ID"].ToString();

// Method 3
string id = httpContext.Request?.Headers["ID"].ToString();

// Method 4
var s = Request.Headers["KEY"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last()
```

Comment: What about `if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("CallerId", out values))`?

Comment: same complain, `Request.Headers`

Comment: Have you debugged to determine exactly what reference is `null`? Are you saying that `Request` is not `null` but `Headers` is? If so then I would think that `Request.Headers?.TryGetValue` should work, but you can'r cast the result as type `bool` because it's actually `bool?`. You would have to compare the result to `true` instead, i.e. `if (Request.Headers?.TryGetValue("CallerId", out values) == true)`.